# jQuery fade in each letter

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

I have a small problem with my fades. Basically when I fade the first letter the second one moves over to the left taking the first letters place. Is there a way to stop this? If so how?

```
$('.m').fadeIn( 4000, function() {
    $('.i').fadeIn( 3000, function() {
        $(this).fadeOut( 2000, function() {
            $('.full' ).fadeOut( 3000 );
        } );    
    } );
    $(this).fadeOut( 3000 );    
} );
```

jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MRvfC/

Comment: I believe `fade` relies on display, which does not hold places like visibility does. Try using `animate` with `opacity`.

Comment: Check out http://www.greensock.com/get-started-js/ for better control over animations like this

Comment: Or look into CSS transitions. I prefer them over JS, and only have issues in IE for which you could use a jQuery fallback if desired. I usually just stick IE users with a sub-par experience in hopes they switch browsers.

Comment: haha that's great! I couldn't agree more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `display` property, you should use `visibility`. Unfortunately jQuery uses `display` in show/hide, so you'll have to do it manually.

```
$('.m').css( {'opacity':0,'visibility':'visible'} ).animate( {'opacity':1}, 4000, function() {
    $('.i').css( {'opacity':0,'visibility':'visible'} ).animate( {'opacity':1}, 3000, function() {
        $(this).animate( {'opacity':0}, 2000, function() {
            $('.full' ).animate( {'opacity':0}, 3000 );
        } );    
    } );
    $(this).animate( {'opacity':0}, 3000 ); 
});
```

and change `display:none` to `visibility:hidden` in the CSS. It's also worth saving some processing power by setting visibility back to hidden at the end, although good browsers will know not to render something with 0 opacity anyway.